# FAILED: HiveAccessControlException Permission denied: Principal [name=user1, type=USER] does not have following privileges for operation CREATETABLE

Tags: azure, hive, hiveql, azure-hdinsight

I am trying to create table using hive create query and getting below error-

```
Error: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: HiveAccessControlException Permission denied: Principal [name=username, type=USER] does not have following privileges for operation CREATETABLE [[OBJECT OWNERSHIP] on Object [type=DATABASE, name=dbname]] (state=42000,code=40000)
```

I tried to give grant createtable but it seems it's not valid grant, How we can give create table grant to hive user, we don't want to give drop database access so can't add user in owner role.

Comment: This is caused by a lack of sufficient permissions on the database. The user creating the Hive table needs read, write, and execute permissions against the database.

When you say "it's not valid grant", how you are granting permissions and please do share more details on the steps which you are trying?

Comment: 0: jdbc:hive2://hiveserver2:10001/default> grant CREATETABLE  to user user1;
Error: Error while processing statement: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. Unsupported privilege type CREATETABLE (state=08S01,code=1)
0: jdbc:hive2://hiveserver2:10001/default>

Answer (score 0):

You are using the incorrect privilege type `CREATETABLE` that's the reason you are experiencing this error message  `Error: Error while processing statement: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. Unsupported privilege type CREATETABLE (state=08S01,code=1)` .

**Supported privilege types:**

```
ALL Privileges

ALTER

Create

Create view

Delete

Drop

Index

Insert

Lock Tables

Select

Show databases

Super
```

**Reference:** [Apache Hive Language Manual](https://www.docs4dev.com/docs/en/apache-hive/3.1.1/reference/AuthDev.html).

Comment: 0: jdbc:hive2://hiveserver2:10001/default> grant create on database database to user user1;
Error: Error while processing statement: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. Unsupported privilege type CREATE (state=08S01,code=1)
0: jdbc:hive2://hiveserver2:10001/default>

Comment: You may checkout this blog which explains on how to grant permissions on hive tables: http://hadooptutorial.info/hive-authorization-models-and-hive-security/